# popen with /dev/fd/n anonymous pipe hangs sub-process

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to use anonymous pipes as substitutes for files read by a sub-process.  The problem I am having is that the sub-process hangs, I think, because it doesn't recognise the end of the "file" (pipe) has been reached.

Here is some sample code of what I'm doing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>

int main()
  {
  int pipefd[2];
  pipe(pipefd);
  fcntl(pipefd[0], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); // necessary?

  char cmd[128];
  snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "cat /dev/fd/%i", pipefd[0]);
  printf("Command: %s\n", cmd);

#if 1
  // This works
  write(pipefd[1], "line1\n", 6);
  write(pipefd[1], "line2\n", 6);
  write(pipefd[1], "line3\n", 6);
  close(pipefd[1]);
#endif

  FILE* fp;
  if ((fp = popen(cmd, "r")) != NULL)
    {
//  fcntl(fileno(fp), F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);  // causes SIGPIPE

#if 0
    // This doesn't work
    write(pipefd[1], "line1\n", 6);
    write(pipefd[1], "line2\n", 6);
    write(pipefd[1], "line3\n", 6);
    close(pipefd[1]);
#endif

    char buffer[1024];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL)
      printf("%s", buffer);
    printf("retcode: %i\n", pclose(fp));
    }

  close(pipefd[0]);

  return 0;
  }
```

The code as given above works.  In it I create a pipe and I create a command using the read end of the pipe, in this case with `cat`.  In the working version, I then write data to the write end of the pipe **then** start the sub-process using `popen` and read stdout from the sub-process until it ends.

What I need to be able to do is move the writing to the pipe **after** the creation of the sub-process (see the `#if 0` block).  Ultimately, it will end up in a separate thread.  However, switching to after the `popen` call means the sub-process doesn't end (hangs) and I cannot see why.

I have tried making the various streams non-blocking, but doing this on the sub-process stream merely results in a SIGPIPE failure.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: Set the FD_CLOEXEC flag for pipefd[1] before doing popen.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks!!  Do you want to make that an answer and I'll mark it done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between doing

```
write(pipefd[1], "line1\n", 6);
write(pipefd[1], "line2\n", 6);
write(pipefd[1], "line3\n", 6);
close(pipefd[1]);
```

before the popen vs after is this: if `pipefd[1]`is open when popen is called, the forked/execed process will also have it open. When that process reads from `pipefd[0]`, it will never see EOF, because that descriptor, the write end of the pipe, remains open.

One fix for this is to set the close-on-exec flag for that file descriptor

```
fcntl(pipefd[1], F_SETFD, fcntl(pipefd[1], F_GETFD) | FD_CLOEXEC);
```

prior to the call to popen.